# How to point domain to Kubernetes cluster without Load Balancer and Ingress controller

Tags: kubernetes, dns

Let's suppose I have bare-metal servers forming a Kubernetes cluster where I am deploying my application. How can I point one domain name to all of the worker nodes of the cluster without a Load Balancing Service or Ingress Controller ?

Answer (score 2):

One suggestion could be to forget its Kubernetes worker nodes, and think about how you will give some domain pointing to a set of instances? Imagine you are running copy of your static website in 10 servers and you want to have same domain to all the nodes? You have either an external load balancer or a reverse proxy. But the biggest question why do you want to do that as worker nodes are short-lived you got to be dynamic about load balancing them right? Thats where a Service or Ingress will help, as it knows when a worker node leaves or gets added to cluster dynamically for you. Checkout these possibilities listed here https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/baremetal/